# Can someone explain why do some images get random classes instead of gettng propper ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-deployment

i have 3 if's that toggles (on/off) a class if there is a logo/thumbnail/graphic string in the .webp file name

```js
var href = $(this).attr('href');
if (href.indexOf('.webp') > 0) {
  var imagebox = document.createElement("div");
  imagebox.className = "imagebox";
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = href;
  imagebox.append(img)
  $("#viewer").append(imagebox)
  //console.log(href);
}

if (href.indexOf('logo') > 0) {
  $(".imagebox").toggleClass("logo");
}
if (href.indexOf('thumbnail') > 0) {
  $(".imagebox").toggleClass("thumbnail");
}
if (href.indexOf('graphic') > 0) {
  $(".imagebox").toggleClass("graphic");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="GalleryContainer">
     <ul>
          <li class="list active" data-filter="imagebox">All</li>
          <li class="list" data-filter="thumbnail">Thumbnails</li>
          <li class="list" data-filter="logo">Logos</li>
          <li class="list" data-filter="graphic">Graphics</li>
     </ul>
     <div id="viewer"></div>
</div>
```

here you can see the
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1fL7.jpg) of the code and webpage

Comment: @ZIMRO When I run your code snippet (hit the blue button) it still gives me an error. (`$(this)` doesn't refer to any specific element right now and there is no `href` attribute in your HTML.) Can you please update your code so that it is an actual [mcve]?

Comment: @Ivar how am i supposed to do it when i cant have images here linking from a folder (as my code does)

Comment: Are you using an external library for the gallery? My guess is that this library is adding classes like "active". Probably there is something along the lines of `$(".GalleryContainer").initGallery()` in your code

Comment: @ZIMRO Your JavaScript will still run even when the images source can't be found. (If you add the `width` and `height` attribute it will render a broken image.) If you want to make it fancy you can link to an image on https://place-hold.it/.